# Select from comma separated list of values into temp table

Tags: mysql

I have a stored procedure which has a parameter `IN id_list VARCHAR(65535)`(due to impossibility of passing array as a parameter). `id_list` is an imploded(glue is comma symbol) array of integers. I used it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `some_procedure`(IN `id_list` VARCHAR(65535))
BEGIN
SET @`query`:= CONCAT(
    'SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `table` AS `tbl`
    WHERE
        `tbl`.`id` IN (',`id_list`,')');
    PREPARE `statement` FROM @`query`;
    EXECUTE `statement`;
END$$
```

But how can I select `id_list` values into a temporary table to JOIN it with some other table in future?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the MySQL function [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `some_procedure` (IN `id_list` VARCHAR(65535))
BEGIN
    SELECT id 
    FROM table
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, id_list);
END
```

But be aware with long weight tables, because FIND_IN_SET ignores your table's indexes.

Hope it helps.